# SQL Server 2008 R2 Grouping

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, grouping

Here is the script I have.

```
select jt.exempt_status as ExemptStatus, COUNT(*) as ExemptCount
from employee as e
join job_title as jt
    on e.job_title = jt.job_title
group by jt.exempt_status
```

When executed it displays

```
ExemptStatus     ExemptCount
-----------------------------    
E                2
N                5
```

What I need it to display without changing the values in the jt.exempt_status field is.

```
ExemptStatus     ExemptCount
-----------------------------    
Exempt           2
Non-Exempt       5
```

Comment: Is there a table containing the description of the exempt_status code?

Comment: @Jeff - for completeness, what RDBMS are you using? SQL Server?  MySQL?  PostgreSQL?  Something else?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `CASE` expression to format your values when selecting them:

```
select CASE jt.exempt_status 
    WHEN 'E' THEN 'Exempt'
    WHEN 'N' THEN 'Non-Exempt'
    END 
    as ExemptStatus, COUNT(*) as ExemptCount
from employee as e
join job_title as jt
    on e.job_title = jt.job_title
group by jt.exempt_status
```